# Run process as with default privileges of current (LocalSystem) user

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, privileges

There is an MSI custom action that would launch an external process. However, on Windows 7 (maybe, Vista too) the custom action, which runs under the LocalSystem account, does NOT have `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privilege. The external process I am launching requires this privilege at some stage. However, it doesn't get the privilege as the parent (running MSI custom action) doesn't have it. This is a known issue on Vista/7 as Microsoft has removed this privilege on the `msiexec.exe` process if custom action (say MSI) runs as a Local System account. IMO, the question doesn't need more information around MSI.

I have tried combinations of `LogonUser`, `SetTokenInformation` (to add a new privilege), set and update linked token, `DuplicateTokenEx`, and eventually `CreateProcessAsUser`. However, the created process will never have the backup privilege enabled no matter how I try.

My simple question is:

- How to run the external process with all the **default** privileges the Local System account would have?

Why does Windows sticks to the restricted token?

I got to know that once the token is created, no more privileges can be added. `SetTokenInformation` will fail. I wonder how to add the privilege to a token (which isn't used yet)!

Related:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a18edd5-88fb-464a-8b57-5c9ec71170dd/windows-installer-45-and-sebackupprivilege
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edbd7f01-aeb2-45ac-9264-9c256ee4b314/how-to-get-sebackupprivilege-in-a-deferred-custom-action-exe
- [CreateProcessAsUser with elevated privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212984/createprocessasuser-with-elevated-privileges?rq=1)
- [How to call LogonUser() to get a non-restricted full token inside a Windows Service with UAC enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403050/how-to-call-logonuser-to-get-a-non-restricted-full-token-inside-a-windows-serv)

Comment: possible open token, which have backup/restore privileges and impersonated with it

Comment: @RbMm, which token to open? Current process's token or its duplicate doesn't give the required privilege in it.

Comment: some system process token. enumerate processes and look for token with privileges which you need.

Comment: I will try that. However, I wonder how will that work if LogoUser doesn't give valid token.

Comment: for what you need LogoUser ? simply use existing token. https://pastebin.com/Gm3dw7Zd

Comment: I mostly got it, but how to launch the new process then? Using the `hNewToken` with CPAU? Or is the current thread already impersonated and then `CreateProcess` would work?

Comment: for what you need launch the new process ?

Comment: `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` then `CreateProcess` or  `CreateProcessAsUser`. It's alternative to `CreateProcessWithTokenW`.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo - `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`  - not have any effect for `CreateProcess` or  `CreateProcessAsUser`. this is wrong. not say already about what sense in create new process

Comment: @YangXiaoPo - `CreateProcess` inherit token of current process, not thread. as result `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` (which simply set token for current thread) not affect this. in case `CreateProcessAsUser` we direct pass token as first argument. and it used. `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` can have effect only in sense - are we will be have *SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege*.. but main - not view sense start new process at all

Comment: @RbMm Why new process? Because MSI custom actions, residing in a DLL, are run by separate *processes*, and my installer engine need to have full control on certain actions not handled by MSI. Consider it as backward-compat issue, but I do need the EXE, which will remain running till last custom action tells the EXE to exit. I did mention that in question correctly that I need to launch the process with SYSTEM's full rights (as custom action is already running under SYSTEM, but with restricted token)

Comment: Does this [PrimaryTokenTheft](https://github.com/slyd0g/PrimaryTokenTheft#primarytokentheft) work for you ?

Comment: @RbMm Your solution has worked for all OSes except for Vista/2008, where it always fails to find the appropriate process with required privileges. Even if it finds a process, process creation fails with 5, 1314, 1349. So, I had to use a different technique in the target process itself to do the registry backup (instead of using `RegSaveKey`, which requires backup privilege).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo, I stopped further research on this and used a different approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Ajay - if i write code - it of course will be work on vista too.

Comment: @rbmm, process enumeration worked, but on CPAU. I launched the process within GetToken function only.

Comment: @Ajay - of course exist processes, which have backup-restore and possible use it token